# Генерация графика

Tags: python, графика, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте.
Скажите пожалуйста, умеет ли Питон, не выводя на экран, отрисовать простейшие диаграммы сразу в файл?
Очень хочется сделать скрипт, который выводил бы на веб-страницу графики, вставленные в виде готовых графических файлов.

Вот как здесь, с треугольником.  [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=triangle+45+40+69](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427erhlo8jk6n):
[image: triangle 45 40 69]

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой модуль [matplotlib](http://pyviy.blogspot.com/2009/09/matplotlib.html) и стоит посмотреть на pyplot